# How can you modify a file after move and replacing another in UWP?

Tags: c#, file, uwp, storagefile

In UWP after calling `MoveAndReplaceAsync` to replace and old file with a new one I cannot modify the new file afterwards.

E.g. Here I open a file and save it in `_file`

```cs
private async void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker =
            new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
            {
                ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
                SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
            };
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

        _file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    }
```

This in this handler I write out to a new file, move and replace it over the opened one and then try to append.

```cs
    private async void MoveAndReplaceAndAppend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a temp file for writing to
        var tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
        var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var tmpFile = await tempFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        try
        {
            var stream = await tmpFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            var dw = new DataWriter(stream);
            dw.WriteString("New file");
            await tmpFile.MoveAndReplaceAsync(_file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var dlg = new MessageDialog($"Error while move and replacing {ex.Message}");
            await dlg.ShowAsync();
        }

        var failures = "";
        try
        {
            await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(_file, "testing");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            failures += $"Failed appending to _file: {ex.Message}\n";
        }

        try
        {
            await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(tmpFile, "testing");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            failures += $"Failed appending to tmpFile: {ex.Message}\n";
        }

        var errorDialog = new MessageDialog($"Error while appending\n{failures}");
        await errorDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

I've tried appending with the old and the new `StorageFile` but always get the following errors.

```
Failed appending to _file: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Failed appending to tmpFile: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: I found some curious behavior. If I call `stream.Dispose()` after writing to the temp file then it works as I expect. This shouldn't be necessary, right?

Comment: It is. you have to close your filestreams after using them. otherwise the files keep locked

Comment: Why don't they close automatically when they go out of scope?

Comment: Oh so these types would require a using block for that, right?

Comment: I wonder why I don't get this warning in a UWP app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2000-dispose-objects-before-losing-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the previous stream's lifetime did not end before replace operations. You could use [`Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.imagestream.dispose) to manage the output stream's lifetime manually.

```
var stream = await tmpFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
var dw = new DataWriter(stream);
dw.WriteString("New file");
stream.Dispose();
```

> Why don't they close automatically when they go out of scope?

It shouldn't be necessary that manage the output stream's lifetime manually. You could also use **`using`** statement to manage stream's lifetime .

```
using (var stream = await tmpFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    var dw = new DataWriter(stream);
    dw.WriteString("New file");
}
```

The stream will be released automatically when execution leaves the **`using`** statement. For more, you could refer [UWP File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).